# Elevation + transparency bug on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, view, android-5.0-lollipop, android-elevation

Using a background color for a view with some alpha (e.g. #99fe0038) and some elevation on API 21 reveals two circles: one for the view itself and another inside:

[image]

Elevation and background color are set via code:

```
view.setElevation(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_elevation_lollipop));
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99fe0038"));
```

Without setting elevation or with using an opaque color everything looks like expected.

Is it an Android bug or have I missed something here?

Comment: Still happening on API 24 and 26 (real device and emulator)... this is the only link I found related to this issue, no body seems to have a solution...
Got here actually from your GitHub:
https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

Removing `shadow effect` worked for me.

```
FAB.setShadow(false);        
FAB.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_transparent));
```